# New to discord.js, bot reads wrong text to verify a particular user when he joins my server

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

So im tryna make a little bot that verifies a particular group of users to access a reserved channel. The bot is supposed to ask a secret code, and when the answer is withing the question, the bot replies to itself and an error message is displayed. How do i fix this code?

I've tried using

```
if(message.author.bot){return;}
```

but it doesnt work for some reason welp

this is my code:

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    const channel = member.guild.channels.find(ch => ch.name === 'vaayil');

    channel.send("type in the secret code");
    client.on('message', message =>{
        if(message.author.bot){return;}
        if(message.content === `secret`){
            channel.send("verified");
        }
        if(message.content !== `secret`){
            channel.send("not verified");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Nesting events like that is generally bad practice.

However, you can avoid doing so, and make your life coding this bot easier. In Discord.js, you can use [`TextChannel.awaitMessages()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages) to wait for messages that pass a certain filter, and then do something with those messages.

Example:

```js
const secretCode = 'sloths';

client.on('guildMemberAdd', async member => {
  const channel = member.guild.channels.find(c => c.name === 'vaayil');
  if (!channel) return console.log('Can\'t find channel.');

  try {
    await channel.send(`What\'s the secret code, ${member}?`);

    const filter = m => m.author.id === member.id;
    const messages = await channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1 });
    const message = messages.first(); // (The only message in the Collection)

    if (message.content === secretCode) {
      await channel.send('That\'s right!');
      // Do something...
    } else {
      await channel.send('Nice try, but wrong.');
      // Do something...
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
});
```